# Selenium cannot find css class

Tags: python, css, selenium, web-scraping

I am following a guide on youtube to build a scraper of the website which requires login. However I am facing a problem with the login button click.

Here is the code so far I am using. It open the website, however it does not press the login button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

url = "https://www.URL.COM"
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.login-top.ng-scope > p.log"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.modal-dialog > ng-pristine.ng-valid.needsclick.ng-empty.error.ng-touched"))).click()
```

Website is Heo dot com; I would like to login to the website however cannot find solution how to enter email, password and login.

Comment: To click on login button, try `"[data-ng-click='showLogin()']"`.

Answer (score 0):

To simply send values to the elements and click to login.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.login-top.ng-scope > p.log"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form > div > input:nth-child(2)"))).send_keys("A")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"form > div > input:nth-child(4)" ))).send_keys("B")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form > div > div > input"))).click()
```

You could alternatively use:

```
input[value='Sign in']
```

use that instead for Sign in as an xpath.

```
input[name='username']
```

for username as an xpath.